# Server error on new web server - response is not available in this context

Tags: c#, .net, web, iis, server

I am trying to move a (running) .net 4.0 web application from a Windows 2008 server to a Windows 2019 server.

I have used the deploy function in IIS Manager (Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager), and installed the following on the new server:

- Message Queuing Server.
- Configuration APIs.
- Custom Logging.
- Dynamic Content Compression.
- HTTP Redirection.
- ASP.
- Server Side Includes.
- ASP.NET 4.7.
- .NET Extensibility 4.7.

However when I am trying to browse the application, I get the following Server Error:

[image]

Hope that someone can help me figure out, what is wrong.

Comment: Is it working if you debug it on your local machine?

Comment: Have you changed the pipeline mode? Note that there are tons of breaking changes, so you should expect some code changes to adapt from classic to integrated, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-20-breaking-changes-on-iis

Comment: I have set up the application pools the same way, as it is on the old server. Both running integrated managed pipeline.

Comment: I have not tried debugging it on my own machine, as I have limited C# and VS knowledge. Our developer is unfortuanetly not contactable anymore, and that is why I tried to move it with the 'deploy' function in IIS. Is this possible? Or do I need to find someone with better knowledge of C#?

Comment: If you don't know C#, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.